# What are the best practices for increasing node connectivity / number of peers?

Tags: node, performance

I'm looking for the way to increase tezos-node connectivity. It seems that the best way is to increase number of peers (or maybe their quality somehow?).
So the question is - how should I configure `config.json` in order to have optimal number of peers connected to my node?

Comment: From your perspective would you want to have as many peers as possible and what exactly is the benefit ?

Comment: @Ezy Last week I experienced a "fitness" issue - when my block was actually injected just on time, but Prio 1 baker injected a block with a fitness higher than my. So I'm trying to dig into this issue and figure out what is the reason. Internet connection is 100% OK, so I assume that it's about peers I've connected to and their quality - I think the reason that my peers didn't show me 1-2 endorsements due to some sort of lag so that's why fitness is a little bit lower.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your side, a first step would be to set `--connections` option to eg. 1000 or 10000 (assuming you have enough resources for that. I remember there was an issue with the number of opened file descriptors in the past that makes the node crash, and attempting to establish too may connection could trigger the issue.).

Then, if you can initialize your node with a "good set of peers" (both in number of peers an in quality), this would also help. For instance, you can copy the running peers shown by tzscan (https://tzscan.io/network) as a starting point.

Note that, a connection to another node can be refused for several reasons: your node has been blacklisted for some reason, the other node considers that it has enough connections, the other peer is not connected at all, ...

Comment: Thanks! Assuming that "good set of peers" could change from time to time - is there a way to automatically connect to them when the node starts? Or I have to manually add them each time?